# how to design complex sql queries in microsoft crm dynamics 2011

Tags: javascript, sql, dynamics-crm

I am trying to get data on my website from a Microsoft CRM Dynamics 2011 backend database.
I need to make a join statement and I don't know how to implement it in CRM.

Comment: Do these links help? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff681573.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa608858(v=ax.10).aspx

Comment: was a good read and very informative, but i am retrieving the data in Javascript... LINQ can't work for me unfortunately.

Comment: Show us some of what you already have. There are different ways to access the CRM data from javascript, so we need to see how you are currently doing it to advise you on how to enhance it to include joins.